# SCSS: Basic function failing during compile. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: function, sass

```css
@function makeColors($color) {
    $new-color: (#red, #green, #blue);
    list.append($new-color, #orange[, $separator]);
    @return $new-color;
}
```

**PrePros (compiling software)** says it won't compile because of

`'Invalid CSS after ...#green, #blue); Expected }, Was list.append($new-...'`

Can I not run multiple commands/functions in an `@function`?

Comment: What did you try to do by writing `[, $separator]`?

Comment: Hi @Arkellys, I got that from here: https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/07/15/understanding-sass-lists/

"append($list, $value[, $separator]): appends $value to the end of $list using $separator as a separator (using the current one if not specified)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

First, using square brackets around an argument as for `[, $separator]` is a way to tell that an argument is optional **in a documentation**. In your code, you should either remove this third argument or replace it with the separator of your choice:

> If $separator is comma, the returned list is comma-separted. If it’s space, the returned list is space-separated. If it’s auto (the default), the returned list will use the same separator as $list (or space if $list doesn’t have a separator). Other values aren’t allowed. - [from sass:list documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list)

So in your case you can write:

```
list.append($new-color, #orange);
```

Second, and this is why you are getting this error, the function `append` returns a **copy** of your list, which means that you either need to store it in a new variable and then return it, or just return it directly:

```
@function makeColors($color) {
   $new-color: (#red, #green, #blue);
   @return append($new-color, #orange);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for this - it will help.